# Why is there difference in the post available fields between Graph API Reference and the exploration tool?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

I'm trying to read some post information about some FB pages/profiles. I'm considering the Graph API version v2.8, and following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post/) documentation.
But there are some fileds accessible from the Graph API that are not listed in the above link, for example the fields is_popular, target, promotion_status and timeline_visibility.

So far, the first two parameters didn't give me any result, but I can obtain both the promotion_status and timeline_visibility results from some posts. How can be possible that the set of the available fields in the reference and in the graph API tool are different for the same version of the API? Should I avoid to request these feelds and lean my word on them?

Comment: You should avoid anything that is not officially documented; it might be changed or removed at any time.

Comment: Ok but, for instance, I use the field full_picture to obtain the high dimensional version of the post image. This field is not included in the list of the above link. I can only ask for the field "picture", this gives me the low dimension version. I've tried the options suggested on stackoverflow like picture.type(large) but I get an error with message "Subfields are not supported by picture"

Comment: Then you either got to live with the “risk” that using undocumented features brings with it; or you could also file a documentation bug and ask them what’s up with this field, and that they should please add it to the docs if it is supposed to “stay”. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/